# Can styles happen one by one after interval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need to make my styles to occur one after another after some interval time.

JS

```
element.style.cssText = "width: 400px; height:400px; background-color:blue; 
border: 1px solid green; border-radius: 10px; text-align: center; color:white; "

setInterval(function () {element.innerHTML += element.style},1000);
```

the styles have to be declerated in JS (not necessarily using .cssText)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying styles is most easily done using the [`classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), rather than with `innerHTML` or `cssText`.

See comments inline:

```js
// Create the CSS dynamically *****************
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML =
  `.backColor { background-color:blue; }
   .width { width:50px; }
   .height { height:100px; }
   .foreColor { color:white; }`;
document.head.appendChild(style);
// *********************************************

const element = document.querySelector("div");

// Array of CSS selector names
const styles = ["backColor", "width", "height", "foreColor"];

let index = 0; // Keeps track of which style to add next

let timer = setInterval(function(){
  // If we've added all the styles
  if(index >= styles.length) { 
    clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer
  }
  
  element.classList.add(styles[index]); // Add the next style
  index++;  // Increase the index
}, 1500);
```

```html
<div>Sample Text</div>
```

Comment: It has to be done without any CSS code

Comment: @rh_a Answer updated to show how to create the CSS dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is written incorrectly.

setting `element.style.cssText` applies the styles from the string given.

Adding `element.style` to `element.innerHTML` will only add text into the element - not what you are looking for.

You should research how [`HTMLElement#style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) and [`Element#innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) work.

Comment: I know it is incorrecct thats why im asking for help

Answer (score -1):

Most simple way is to iterate over an array containing style like this :-

```
const cssText = "width: 400px; height:400px; background-color:blue; 
border: 1px solid green; border-radius: 10px; text-align: center; color:white; ";
const stylesArray = cssText.split(";");
let i = 0;
let timer = setInterval(function () {
    element.style += styleArray[i++];
// or your
// element.innerHTML += styleArray[i++];
    if ( i >= stylesArray ) clearInterval(timer);
},1000);
```

Comment: Inline styles should be avoided whenever possible since they are the hardest to override.